# ASP.NET MVC 5 ValidationMessageFor for a foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following model classes, using VS 2017, EF and MVC 5.0

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }  
}

public class Genre
{
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Genre Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

In the View, I have following code

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlbumId)

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenreId, "GenreId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", String.Empty)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreId)
 </div>
 </div>
```

When I run the code through VS, the view is displayed with GenreId with a dropdown list box. The dropdown includes a blank value , in addition to the values present in the table Genre.

When I select blank from the dropdown and click "save", an error message is displayed

> GenreId field is required

I don't understand where the message is coming from.

In the model class `Album`, there is no `Required` annotation for the `GenreId` property. So how does ASP.NET MVC know to validate the `GenreId`?

Also, why is a blank value displayed in the dropdown list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Album
{
 public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
 public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
 public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
 public virtual string Title { get; set; }
 public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
 public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
 public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
 public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }  
}
```

According to your poco class GenreId have to be int value and can not be null.
if you write like this in the below, you generate non-required field.

```
  public virtual Nullable<int> GenreId { get; set; }
```

Lastly, Razor and MVC can generate default error message if you use or etc.

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor()
```

Note: You use string.empty  in the second parameter. This parameter can set default value of Dropdown.
     @Html.DropDownList(,string.empty)

Hva a nice coding ;)

Comment: How can I change the error message for the dropdown , to a custom error message ?

Comment: Also, why is there a blank value being displayed in the dropdownlist to begin with ?

Comment: @SudhirJangam, If you use  @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", String.Empty) this will set null placeholder message about on String.Empty.

Comment: @SudhirJangam, If you want to change the dipslayed error message you can    Html.ValidationMessageFor razor components. f the answers are correct, please set as correct answer to my answer :)

Comment: I was able to set the custom error message. I still do not undestand why a blank option is being displayed in the dropdown to beginwith, Is there a way to automatically remove it ? before page being displayed

Comment: You can use @Html.DropDownList('GenderId','please select gender') like this

Comment: Another options jquery or create a viewmodel and use selected list in backend sides. You can look at 'SelectedList and DropDown in razor'

Comment: @SudhirJangam did you help you, if it's cpuld you please click yellow check :)